# Identity Server 4 Copy Scopes from request to response

Tags: identityserver4

I'm trying to set up a scenario in using Identity Server 4 where a client that requests a scope "selected-company/database" would receive a claim in it's token of "selected-company/database".

It looks like the parameterized scope was recognised, validated by a ICustomAuthorizeRequestValidator. In the validator I can see the scope and output a scope claim:

```
                    var authdb = context.Result.ValidatedRequest.ValidatedResources.ParsedScopes.FirstOrDefault(s => s.ParsedName == "selected-company");
                    if (authdb != null)
                    {
                        allowscopes.Add(authdb.RawValue);
                        claims.Add(new System.Security.Claims.Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Scope, authdb.RawValue));
                    }
```

And when looking at the PersistedGrants in my SQLite database, I can see that a scope claim of type "selected-company/database" does exist in the database:

```
            {
                "Type": "scope",
                "Value": "selected-company/ERL_CRP",
                "ValueType": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
            },
```

My problem is that it looks as though the claims that the user receives are created via GenerateClaimsAsync where I'm able to add any claim that I want by looking up the current server permission config. The problem is that I can't get back to the original claims from this point in the program, so I can't pass over the parameters that were requested by the client. Is there a class that I can inject into my  UserClaimsPrincipalFactory that would get me access to the persisted token?

My constructor signature looks as follows:

```
 public ADCustomUserClaimsPrincipalFactory(
     UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
     IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor,
     ILogger<ADCustomUserClaimsPrincipalFactory> logger,
     IServiceProvider sp
     )
     : base(userManager, optionsAccessor)
```

Thanks